# What is the difference between the float and integer data type when the size is the same?

Tags: java, floating-point, integer

What the difference between the float and integer data type when size is same?

Comment: I think you mean `float` and `int`. The classes `Float` and `Integer` are wrappers for these. They are also the same size. ;)

Answer (score 115):

- `float` stores floating-point values, that is, values that have potential decimal places
- `int` only stores integral values, that is, whole numbers

So while both are 32 bits wide, their use (and representation) is quite different. You cannot store 3.141 in an integer, but you can in a `float`.

Dissecting them both a little further:

In an integer, *all* bits except the leftmost one are used to store the number value. This is (in Java and many computers too) done in the so-called *two's complement*, which support negatives values. Two's complement uses the leftmost bit to store the positive (0) or negative sign (1). This basically means that you can represent the values of −2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup> − 1.

In a float, those 32 bits are divided between three distinct parts: The sign bit, the exponent and the mantissa. They are laid out as follows:

```
S EEEEEEEE MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

There is a single bit that determines whether the number is negative or non-negative (zero is neither positive nor negative, but has the sign bit set to zero). Then there are eight bits of an exponent and 23 bits of mantissa. To get a useful number from that, (roughly) the following calculation is performed:

> *M* × 2<sup>*E*</sup>

(There is more to it, but this should suffice for the purpose of this discussion)

The mantissa is in essence not much more than a 24-bit integer number. This gets multiplied by 2 to the power of the exponent part, which, roughly, is a number between −128 and 127.

Therefore you can accurately represent all numbers that would fit in a 24-bit integer but the numeric range is also much greater as larger exponents allow for larger values. For example, the maximum value for a `float` is around 3.4 × 10<sup>38</sup> whereas `int` only allows values up to 2.1 × 10<sup>9</sup>.

But that also means, since 32 bits only have 4.2 × 10<sup>9</sup> different states (which are all used to represent the values `int` can store), that at the larger end of `float`'s numeric range the numbers are spaced wider apart (since there cannot be more unique `float` numbers than there are unique `int` numbers). You cannot represent some numbers exactly, then. For example, the number 2 × 10<sup>12</sup> has a representation in `float` of 1,999,999,991,808. That might be *close* to 2,000,000,000,000 but it's not exact. Likewise, adding 1 to that number does not change it because 1 is too small to make a difference in the larger scales `float` is using there.

Similarly, you can also represent very small numbers (between 0 and 1) in a `float` but regardless of whether the numbers are very large or very small, `float` only has a precision of around 6 or 7 decimal digits. If you have large numbers those digits are at the start of the number (e.g. 4.51534 × 10<sup>35</sup>, which is nothing more than 451534 follows by 30 zeroes – and `float` cannot tell anything useful about whether those 30 digits are actually zeroes or something else), for very small numbers (e.g. 3.14159 × 10<sup>−27</sup>) they are at the far end of the number, way beyond the starting digits of 0.0000...

Comment: It's worth noting that even though the two datatypes have the same size (32-bit), the bit pattern used to represent the same number in the two datatypes is vastly different. E.g. the bit pattern for the unsigned integer 1 is 00....001, while the bit pattern for the floating-point 1.0 would be something else entirely.

Comment: A subtle point is that floating point numbers do not actually support decimal places.  Instead of a decimal point, they have a radix point.  In all practical cases, the radix is 2.  (Decimal floats have been standardized by IEEE, but are not in wide use.)  This distinction can be important, especially in applications that are sensitive to rounding, like financial apps.

Comment: @Kevin: Indeed. I kept this answer very shallow, though, since I think if someone doesn't even know the difference between FP and integral types there is a lot of explaining still to do. But yes, you pretty much never want floating-point numbers to get near monetary values.

Comment: @Ammaro: The mantissa has an implied first bit of 1. Which means that it's actually 24 bits long, even though only 23 are contained in the data structure.

Comment: Well then what is even the point of integers data type? When all integers can be simply written as floating point numbers to begin with.

Comment: @William: You can fit 2^32 integers into a 32-bit int, but only 2^23 integers into a 32-bit float. (at least if you still want to retain the ability to do exact calculations).

Answer (score 3):

Floats are used to store a wider range of number than can be fit in an integer. These include decimal numbers and scientific notation style numbers that can be bigger values than can fit in 32 bits. Here's the deep dive into them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should say 32 bits... 2^32 is the number of values that can be represented with 32 bits. 2^32 bits would be ~4 gigabits (or 4 gibibits)... and you can surely represent larger values with that than you can with a single precision float.

Answer (score 0):

Joey's answer is quite good. You might check the below calculation in Python.. It shows how the 32bit float maximum and minimum are obtained. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.
Hope it's helpful.

```
import math
def convertToIntegerLessThanK(K):
    return int(K) if K > 0 else int(K) - 1

E = [-126, 127]
n = 23
converted_power = math.log(2,10) * E[1]
ten_power = convertToIntegerLessThanK(converted_power)
fraction = converted_power - ten_power

maximum_M = (2 - pow(2, -n))
significant_part = pow(10, fraction) * maximum_M

print(str(significant_part) + "e" + str(ten_power))


# compute minimum float significant part
converted_power = math.log(2,10) * E[0]
ten_power = convertToIntegerLessThanK(converted_power)
fraction = converted_power - ten_power

minimum_M = (1+ pow(2, -n))
significant_part = pow(10, fraction) * minimum_M

print(str(significant_part) + "e" + str(ten_power))
#3.402823466385235e38
#1.1754944909521525e-38
```