# Why can't I pass a large value as an Int32?

Tags: c#, floating-point, int32

I have a number: 94,800,620,800

Float is 4-byte data-type.
Int32 is also 4-byte data-type.

```
float f = 94800620800; // ok
Int32 t = 94800620800; // error
```

Please explain this problem. Why I get a error when using Int32. Why I can use this number for float data-type because both of them are 4-byte data-type. Thanks.

Comment: `Int32` maxvalue is  2,147,483,647, that's why there is the error

Comment: A float is a floating point value. An int is an integer value.

Comment: You should correctly title your question. You are willing to understand why two types, both represented with 4 Bytes, don't have the same restrictions.

Comment: I'll add that float has 7 digits precision. Try `Console.WriteLine(94800620800f == 94800620801f);`

Comment: But both of them are 4-byte data-type. Why Int32 can't store this value???

Comment: Lu Lu try reading how does float store data...

Comment: [what the difference between the float and integer data type when the size is same in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806944/what-the-difference-between-the-float-and-integer-data-type-when-the-size-is-same) and/or [floating point entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the number you are trying to assign is larger than the [largest possible value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) for a number of type `Int32`, which happens to be 2,147,483,647. To note, the maximum value for a `Single` is [3.402823 × 10<sup>38</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.maxvalue.aspx).

Comment: Because of the internal mechanisms used to calculate the desired numbers from the data stored in bytes, for instance multiplication with integers and exponentiation with real numbers.

Comment: No, value you are trying to pass is 5 bytes - 0x16128EAD00

Answer (score 5):

The max value for Int32 is 2,147,483,647 - which is less than 94,800,620,800.

A float can take a value in the following range: ±1.5 × 10−45 to ±3.4 × 1038

Also, check out this SO question - [what the difference between the float and integer data type when the size is same in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806944/what-the-difference-between-the-float-and-integer-data-type-when-the-size-is-same).  It's a Java question, but the concept is the same and there's a detailed explanation of the difference, even though they're the same size.

Answer (score 3):

Because that number is too big for a 4 byte int. Scalar values like `Int32` have a minimum and maximum limit (which are -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 in this case, respectively), and you simply can't store a value outside this range.

Floating point numbers are stored totally differently, so you won't get compiler errors with huge values, only possible precision problems later, during runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Because of those types internal representation.

`float` uses something like i,d ^ n where i is the integral part, d is the decimal part and n is the exponent (of course, this happens in base 2).

In this way, you can store bigger numbers in a `float`, but it won't be accurate as a, say, `Int32` in storing integral numbers. If you try to convert

```
float f = 94800620800;
```

to an integral type large enough to store its value, it may not be the same as the initial 94800620800.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should read the error message? ;)

```
Error   Integral constant is too large
```

the maximum valiue of a 32 bit int is 2,147,483,647

the float on the other hand works because it stores a mantissa and exponent, rather than just a single number, so it can cope with a much bigger range at the expense of possibly losing precision

try printing out your float and you will get `94800620000` instead of `94800620800` as the lower bits are lost

Answer (score 1):

Integers types are exact representations, while floating point numbers are a combination of significant digits and exponent.

The [floating point wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) is explaining how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Int32 has a max value of 2,147,483,647. Your value is much higher.

Take a look at [system.int32.maxvalue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Provided value of the constant expression is not within the range of int datatype.

Answer (score 0):

The range of Int32 goes from  − 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Your variable is way out of range.