# Questions about 64-bit stuff (in MATLAB)

Tags: floating-point, integer

Here's my question based on what I understand from the book I'm reading. Hopefully, someone can understand my rough idea:

1) Say we have 64 bits. Each bit is either 0 or 1. So 64 bits can only have 64 spots to store `0`s or `1`s. But 10^380 is a very long (and huge number). We need 380 spots to write down 10^380, i.e., 10...000. Then how could it be possible for computer to store this number? I'm totally lost here.

2)"uint64" data type means computer require 64 bits to store such a number. The maximum integer of this type it can store is 2^64 - 1. Comparing to "double", which also uses 64 bits to store a fractions. Yet the largest number it can store is 1.79x10^380. 10^380 is a very very large number, in comparison to 2^64. How could this be? I mean why don't we just throw away (literally throw away) "uint64" because it uses the same amount of memory like "double" and can store even larger numbers.

Unless I'm crazy here, or misunderstand something, someone please help explain. Thanks!

P.s.: Please don't direct me to any "too-general" link, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point. I'd read many websites before posting my questions. I need some sort of easy-to-understand answers.

Comment: how is this related to matlab at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the float and integer data type when the size is the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806944/what-is-the-difference-between-the-float-and-integer-data-type-when-the-size-is)

Comment: I would recommend you do a google search for the types to find out for yourself how the bits are allocated. There is a fundamental difference to [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) and [int](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)). Further, I would say that int64 is a better comparison than uint64 since the latter lacks the sign bit (and can thus have a range [0,10^64-1]).

Comment: Further, for the records, the maximum value of a double is about ±10−308 for double precision [IEEE 754-1985](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=2355). For a simple summary see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

Comment: The answer in the link provided by @patrik is valid for you (even if it's in the `java` category. Your question is not related to `Matlab` but to how values are represented in a computer (for any language).

Comment: @Hoki The answer is indeed related to Matlab: or rather how matlab choose to implement floating point format. However, since matlab follows the IEEE 754 standard as well as Java (and probably almost any language) the link still applies.

Comment: @patrik, yes I could have been more specific. But understanding the basic difference between `floating-point` and `integer` representations of numbers is important (primordial?) in any language (regardless of their specific implementations of these 2 types, and their many size variants `8/16/32/64/128` bits etc).

Comment: @Hoki You are of course right. The exact bit allocation does not seem to be the main issue here. This question seems to be more about general knowledge. To all: Even if the bit allocation is not exactly known, it is extremely important to have an idea about how accurate floating point numbers are. Especially when performing matrix operations, where the matrix condition number will further decrease the accuracy.

Comment: @patrik I understand now that the fundamental difference between float and int is how they are represented. float is split up in 3 parts (even though the mechanism of this is still a mysterious to me--e.g., when I type x = 1.34256, how does computer actually split this number into 3 parts?). On the other hand, all the ints stay the same, i.e. they are exact.
Question time: what do you mean by this, " it is extremely important to have an idea about how accurate floating point numbers are"? And how can I "have an idea" of this? Could you please clarify further?

Comment: @patrik I did read the link that provided above. Here's what I didn't understand. I think it relates somehow to what you said about accuracy of floating point.
"You cannot represent some numbers exactly, then. For example, the number 2 × 1012 has a representation in float of 1,999,999,991,808. That might be close to 2,000,000,000,000 but it's not exact. Likewise, adding 1 to that number does not change it because 1 is too small to make a difference in the larger scales float is using there."

Comment: @HuyTruong Did you also read the link I provided about [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)? It is all explained there in a good way, including how the exponent and mantissa is choosen. It also says that the leftmost bit is the sign. The exponent is 11 bits for a double. The largest and smallest possible values depend on how you bias the floating-point numbers. The mantissa is 52 bits with gives an accuracy of about 16 digits. You should really read the links I provided (except maybe the complicated IEEE standard link).

Answer (score 0):

The largest number a double might be able to store is 1.79x10^380. But a double or float lacks **accuracy**. For simplicity, let's say a double or float consists of 2 sections of bits, let's say A and B where:

```
double_number = A*2^B
```

If you think about it, the number of bits for A plus the number of bits in B must be constant. So if you want to store a bigger number, you increase the number of bits for B. But then you have less bits over for A which means you have less accuracy. So a UInt64 certainly won't be thrown out, because it works well to whole number accuracy. But a double can store a number the same size as a UInt64's maximum number, but not to the same accuracy. Maybe you can check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Comment: I would rather say that the fundamental difference lies in how the types are represented. Integer types are only ones and zeroes (plus the sign bit for some types), while double have an exponential part and a mantissa. Of course it is possible to perform calculations with integer types, which can give a result which is higher than the largest possible int by using fixed.point arithmetics.

Comment: I totally agree. I just tried to answer the question in a very simple fashion. My answer probably should be edited (or deleted).