# Why are float numbers rounded up in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I created Cassandra table with column type: DataType.FLOAT.

Execute my SQL using CqlSession:

```
CqlSessionBuilder builder = CqlSession.builder();
        builder.addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress(properties.getHost(), properties.getPort()));
        builder.withLocalDatacenter(properties.getDatacenter());
        builder.withAuthCredentials(properties.getUsername(), properties.getPassword());
        builder.build();
```

But when I insert float numbers, it's rounded up:

```
12334.9999 -> 12335.0.
0.999999   -> 0.999999
12345.9999 -> 12346.0
```

It seems like Cassandra rounds the float and consider the number of all digits, not only after the point.

What are the options to solve this problem? I know that I can use Decimal datatype, but may be you have other solution?

Answer (score 2):

I actually covered this issue with Apache Cassandra and DataStax Astra DB in an article I wrote last month:

[The Guerilla Guide to Building E-commerce Product Services with DataStax Astra DB](https://datastax.medium.com/the-guerilla-guide-to-building-e-commerce-product-services-with-datastax-astra-db-2bcdf7199436)

So the problem here, is that `FLOAT` is a *fixed* floating point precision type.  This means that when the numeric values are converted from base-10 (decimal) to base-2 (binary), each one of the 32 binary precision points *must* have a value (zero or one, obviously).  It's during this conversion process between base-2 and base-10 that rounding errors occur.  The likelihood of a rounding error increases as the value does (on either side of the decimal point).

> What are the options to solve this problem? I know that I can use Decimal datatype, but may be you have other solution?

Well, you mentioned the best solution (IMO), which to use a `DECIMAL` to store the value.  This works, because `DECIMAL` is an `arbitrary` floating point type.  The values in a `DECIMAL` type are stored in base-10, so there's no conversion necessary and only the required precision is used.

Before arbitrary precision types came along, we used to use `INTEGER`s for things that had to be accurate.  The first E-commerce team I worked on stored product prices in the DB as *pennies*, to prevent the rounding issue.

Yes, both `INT` and `FLOAT` are fixed precision types, but an `INT` stores whole numbers, and all of its precision points can be used for that.  Therefore the usage patterns of the bits are quite different.  While both `INT` and `FLOAT` allocate a bit for the "sign" (+/-), with floating point numbers the remaining 31 precision points are pre-allocated for the full numeric value *and its exponent*.

So your example of 12334.9999 is essentially stored in Cassandra like this:

123349999 x 10^-4

And of course, that's stored in binary, which I won't include here for brevity.

**tl;dr;**

Basically `FLOAT`s use fixed precision to store values as a *formula* (significand and exponent) in base-2, and the conversion back to base-10 makes rounding errors likely.

You're right, use a `DECIMAL` type.  When you need to be exact, that's the only real solution.

If you're interested, here are two additional SO answers which provide more detail on this topic:

- [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)
- [What is the difference between the float and integer data type when the size is the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806944/what-is-the-difference-between-the-float-and-integer-data-type-when-the-size-is)

Comment: This is a super-awesome answer! 